# Columns Stacking on Foundation

Tags: html, email, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm trying to create an e-mail template using Foundation for e-mails.

This is my code snippet:

```
<container class="card-spacer">
    <row>
        <columns small="12" large="6">
            <img src="https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/0/18419730/bb6821c381f4616717178beca3929af7.jpg" style="display: inline-block;"
        </columns>
        <columns small="12" large="6">
            <p class="zfb-zero-margin-paragraph zfb-primary-text-font text-right">Get more insights and analytics on your ads</p>
            <p class="zfb-zero-margin-paragraph zfb-body-text-font text-right">View web dashboard for XYZ <a href="www.xyz.com" class="text-color-gold">www.xyz.com</a></p>
        </columns>  
    </row>
</container>
```

I'd like to have the image and the text, which are in different columns to appear side-by-side on larger devices (like desktop e-mail clients) and stack upon one another on mobile clients.

Any insights on how I can achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Columns in a flex grid will not wrap if not given an explicit size—this is what allows the magical auto-sizing to work. To make columns stack on smaller screens, add the class .small-12 manually.

To switch back to the expand behavior from a percentage or shrink behavior, use the classes .medium-expand or .large-expand. In the below example, the columns stack on small screens, and become even-width on large screens.

```
    <div class="row">
       <div class="small-12 large-expand columns">One</div>
       <div class="small-12 large-expand columns">Two</div>
    </div>

    For more information check its document
    http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flex-grid.html
```